# Trying to parse a JSON file from a URL

Tags: javascript, json

This is the json I am using: [json](https://teamtreehouse.com/anthonyscott4.json)

I want to be able to pull different data out of it and display it on a webpage. Particularly the badge name and related info. The badges array is giving me trouble.

I have taken a look at the jquery documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/
but they kind of lost me because it doesn't match what I am trying to do.

Here is the js file I tried with no luck... Thanks

`

```
//Function to print message to console
function printMessage(badgeCount, points, arr) {
  const message = `Anthony Scott has ${badgeCount} total badge(s) and ${points} points in JavaScript. here is a list of badges ${arr}`;

    document.write(message);
}

(function() { 
   $.getJSON("https://teamtreehouse.com/anthonyscott4.json", {})
     .done(function(data) {
            // Parse the data
                const profile = JSON.parse(data);                            
                // Print the data
                                let arr = [];
                                for(var x in profile.badges) {
                                    arr.push(profile.badges[x].name)
                                }
                document.write(profile.badges.length, profile.points.JavaScript, arr);
     });

});
```

`

Comment: Your data is already an object. No need to parse it. The javascript interpreter has already parsed it for you. https://jsfiddle.net/sumitridhal/bapxdenw/

Comment: Parse using `jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `$.getJSON` the `JSON` is already parsed for you in the callback, so there is no need to call `JSON.parse` on the result.

`for in` loops are used to [iterate over an objects properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). What you are looking for is a normal `for` loop or `forEach`

```js
var request = $.getJSON('https://teamtreehouse.com/anthonyscott4.json');
request.done(function (response) {
  var badges = [];
  response.badges.forEach(function (badge) {
    badges.push(badge.name);
  });
  $('#result').append(badges.toString());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Example with `for` loop:

```js
var request = $.getJSON('https://teamtreehouse.com/anthonyscott4.json');
request.done(function (response) {
  var badges = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < response.badges.length; ++i) {
    var badge = response.badges[i];
    badges.push(badge.name);
  }
  $('#result').append(badges.toString());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```